# Ideal diode P-channel + matched transistor

Tags: mosfet, diodes, rectifier, p-channel

I've eventually replicated the ideal diode as described in this [schematic using a matched transistor pair](https://www.electro-tech-online.com/articles/simple-inexpensive-ideal-diode-mosfet-circuits.817/).

[image]

It seemed to be working fine at first, but my V<sub>DS</sub> is around 6-700 mV at only 8 A which is nowhere near where it should be.

So I started investigating and it seems my V<sub>GS</sub> is only 60 mV which would explain the very high R<sub>DS(on)</sub>, but I can't think of a good reason why.

Here is the schematic I used to route my PCB. I doubt it is of great interest given it's an exact copy of the one above, but I'm including it for the sake of completeness:

[image]

I've also replicated the op-amp schematic and I also get 6-700 mV V<sub>DS</sub> @ 8A.

[image]

Any lead I could follow?

Comment: Is the direct connection from Q1a base to collector by intention? This looks a bit strange. Anyway, the transistor Q1b turns on and therefore the voltage on it's collector is only Vce away from "Out" and this is what you get on the gate. It functions like it is wired, but the wiring is odd.

Comment: Have you made sure that anyone has ever built the circuit you cite and had it work properly? Lots of such circuits out there that get written up with only a cursory look and they never have in fact worked. Not sure about this one. DMMT3906W is two dies on one leadframe so while the production process does the selection, it's not as good as an integrated pair would be...

Comment: It would help to note that the diagram and waveforms you show are from *someone else's* simulation. So, have you actually simulated it yourself? If so, post *your* results. Have you built it yet? Otherwise it's all a bit of a theoretical discussion...

Comment: *which would explain the very high RdsOn* RdsOn is the channel impedance. The mosfet is turned off so there's no channel, so Rds is "infinity". The voltage you're measuring is the body diode forward voltage.

Comment: *I've also replicated the AOP schematic* What AOP schematic? Please edit the question to fill in all those missing details.

Comment: Do you get a Vgs of several volts at *at all*, i.e. at any load current? Or is it always close to zero?

Comment: @datenheim I cannot say about the intention behind the direct connection since I haven't designed the circuit.

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica Yes, it is indeed someon else's simulation, I thought the link and the fact that I replicated made it clear but I realize it might not be the case.
I'm attaching the AOP schematic.
Regarding the RdsON, I'm merely calculating it via the Vds and the current when it is conducting, (when current is flowing in the right way).

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica
Regarding Vgs, nope it stays around 60mV at any load.

Comment: @datenheim With IN<OUT, Q1b is turned on. With IN>OUT, Q1b turns off since the B-E diode gets reverse-biased. R1 and R2 are different and that's probably where most of the problem lies. This circuit needs a better "current mirror". At least there needs to be a third transistor that buffers the base potential so that the left branch isn't loaded more than the right branch. That's why R1 is smaller than R2. This circuit, to work properly, must have identical R's, and then the topology has to be improved until it starts working. I doubt very much that it got any real-life testing in a circuit.

Comment: @VoltsAndNuts Please don't use the "AOP" acronym. It's meaningless to most people. And please just post your own results and schematics. You say that you "replicated it". I don't see anything of yours here, so maybe your replication has a problem? How could we tell. Show the circuit **you** have tested/simulated, not someone else's pictures. Until the pictures are *yours*, there's no way we can help with *your* problem. Perhaps there's a trivial mistake in *your* schematic that we can see but you are missing. That's why it's so important not to just say "I replicated" without showing your work

Comment: @Kubahasn'tforgottenMonica What *is* "AOP"? I've seen it from a few people, but never really got what it means.

Comment: AOP is Op-Amp, sorry for the confusion, edited it in the answer.

I've also included my schematic which is the exact copy of the DMMT one. As it seems from the comment of the original schematic, people have used this circuit with success.

Comment: With only 3.7V of bias available, I would expect that the pass transistor isn't going to be turned on hard enough to achieve the ultimate low Rds(on). Try the sim with an external bias.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that your Vgs limits how hard the FET can be turned on. With a more-negative reference for the BJT pair the Rds(on) improves.

Here's a quick sim to demonstrate the effect ([simulate it here](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?ctz=CQAgjCAMB0l3BWEAmM0EE4DMGAcB2ZLMSANjABYxkQtcQkKsGBTAWjDACgB3cZepxphS4alF7hRFQaNIUJfESHkgZKhZEnrV6rDS0AnKRpNCoKhPC7Hq9VXbEHw8OJMfrHqrUtHLlbBiiWgAuavT6JpGQIBwWMJC4TLi4pHiQ+mQIYPguMQAmLABmAIYArgA2IVxhQbTCAvUWcWwwCKjEyMhMGGDtSRixbRT4CPiQhMhpGFYYgyQFxeVVXEWmbDoKgaJYzGhIfdoRNHXRR7F1AXU+ILgx2-z0DzeOD47KN6ob9pqKpjEiGJA9ykIFSGLeEEQhReTSSbr3OoIkxaABuKAoMTuGIBwVoahiyHQKGJQPQIIuojYkWeXAASrEaXU2F9rhZMbRoLkwW0uABzHG3QkctlGcGUlDdCVkijwqUPZG03yIvyNWkAByFsQ8T3e8XOHEa6iVWsN9GxGpAzM2sU8+r41sEauu9MeTjdlF+MQ5PKg5IA9uBBt4CXMGPxoPRCUH8QAZf0lfJcQPIXIhpgIBREpAwCAAkAANXyAGdk7RoezIHgUGS8+BC3zSymFOmq4MDkSoygMfi6SxiwBLYshf2GAA6xYAkgB6AtcOhNABidY4YLiBf9VRKfJYXCAA)):

[image]

As you sweep the current mirror bias between 0 and -10V, you'll see Vgs increase and Vds decrease.

- At 0V bias, Vds drop is -277mV
- At -10V bias, Vds drop is -60mV

In this sim FET 'beta' is set to 15. Modify as appropriate for your target FET, using the worksheet at https://www.falstad.com/circuit/mosfet-beta.html

As it is, the IRF7404 is rated at -6.7A @ 25 deg.C, so 8A is really more than this FET can handle. Nevertheless, to achieve the max low 'forward' ideal-diode drop it needs more Vgs drive.

FET link: https://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/power/mosfet/p-channel/irf7404/

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems with the original circuit, the primary one is low gain and biasing as-if this was a current mirror, where - instead - a differential pair biasing is called for.

It also won't work at such a low voltage due to the Vgs(th) of the PMOSfet. A microcurrent oscillator and a charge pump would be needed to fully turn on the mosfet at single-cell voltages. Parts of this circuit could also be redesigned using small-signal mosfets - I'll revisit that later.

We essentially want a comparator built out from a differential pair. If such a comparator is driven from low impedance nodes, the drive voltage can be equivalently provided on the emitters or on the bases. That's what this circuit does.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6AMnh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A differential pair with emitter inputs only needs a bias current on the bases. R5 takes care of it. R3 and R4 suppress positive feedback across the comparator, with R5 acting as a long tail load, "reflected" to the common base node instead of the common emitter node. That's why R5 can be pretty large: its conductance is multiplied by the current gain of the pair, acting as-if it was at the common emitter node.

R6 decreases the gain of the left leg of the differential pair when the diode is turned on.

Some compensation will be necessary if R9 is much larger (say 1k or more).

This circuit was built and performs reasonably with right side at 5V and left side between 0V and 10V.